# Changing a menu's target nodes for each page

Tags: 7, routes

For a Drupal 7 website, I need to have 2 types of menus: 1 menu with a list of countries, each menu entry pointing to a given node. For each country page, I need to display a 'characteristics' menu, with fixed items (e.g. population, incomes), but (of course) the targeted nodes have to be changed in function of the current country. (Clicking on the 'characteristics' menu entries opens a page which is different for each country.)

Is there a module for that in Drupal 7, or a way to do that programmatically?

Comment: What is it that makes one node have 5 items in the characteristics menu and another node only have 3 menu items for example?

Comment: In principle, there should be always the same number of items in the menus, only the link associated to the menu items would change for each page.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question: the best is to use a programmatic approach by using the `l()` function that is available anywhere within a Drupal installation. It accepts three arguments:

- $text: The text that will be visible to users for your link
- $path: The URL that the link will go to when clicked.
- $options: An associative array which allows to set additional parameters to further customize the link with CSS classes etc…

A good introduction is found here: http://www.pixelclever.com/how-and-why-use-l-function-create-links-drupal-programming.
This function can be used in the template files, or directly from a node body.